# Can't I access session scope variable using @ManagedProperty?

Tags: jsf, session-scope, managed-property

I know I can put/get session scope variables like this.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getSessionMap().put(SESSION_KEY_SOME, some);
```

Then can't I access the value like this?

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SomeOtherBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{sessionScope.some}")
    private Some some;
}
```

The value is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ManagedProperty` runs during creation/instantiation of the `@ManagedBean`.

So, when the `@ManagedBean` is created *before* the `#{sessionScope.some}` is set for first time, then it will still remain `null` in the `@ManagedBean`. It will only work when `@ManagedBean` is created *after* the `#{sessionScope.some}` is set for the first time.

There are basically three ways to achieve the desired behavior.

1. Replace `private Some some` by `externalContext.getSessionMap().get("some")`.

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   @SessionScoped
   public class SomeOtherBean {

       public void someMethod() {
           Some some = (Some) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
               .getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("some");
           // ...
       }

   }
   ```
2. Replace `@SessionScoped` by `@RequestScoped`.

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   @RequestScoped
   public class SomeOtherBean {

       @ManagedProperty("#{sessionScope.some}")
       private Some some;

       // ...
   }
   ```
3. Replace `externalContext.getSessionMap().put("some", some)` by directly setting it as bean property.

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   public class SomeBean {

       @ManagedProperty("#{someOtherBean}")
       private SomeOtherBean someOtherBean;

       public void someMethod() {
           // ...
           someOtherBean.setSome(some);
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)